# QueryDSL conditional order by

Tags: sql, querydsl

I would like to translate native sql such as:

```
ORDER BY (currency = 'EUR') DESC, money DESC
```

into query dsl:

```
.orderBy((qItem.currency.eq("EUR")).desc(), qItem.money.desc());
```

However it throws:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: = near line 4, column 31
...
order by qItem.currency = ?1 desc]
```

What am I missing?

Edit:
**Answer (java)**

```
NumberExpression<Integer> currency = new CaseBuilder().when(qItem.currency.eq("EUR"))
            .then(1)
            .otherwise(2);

query.orderBy(currency.asc(), qItem.money.desc());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CASE` instead:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN currency = 'EUR' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) DESC,
         money DESC
```