# JPA sorting by condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot 2.1.9
Ihave some repositories extended QuerydslPredicateExecutor and I need to sort enteties by specific value, plain sql works fine

```
select * from attachment_points order by kpp =1 desc;
```

I have about 50 entitis to add sorting, is there a way to add sorting to existing method

`Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);`

I've tried to add sort to pagable

`JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.DESC, "kpp=1")`

but I've dot error

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property kpp=77 found for type AttachmentPoint!] with root cause
```

Comment: What database are you using? kpp = 1 in the sort is not supported by JPA and also not by all databases.

Comment: I'm using Postgres.  Found the solution: query DSL Qsort with OrderSpecifiers 
thanks to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023675/querydsl-conditional-order-by
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673213/how-to-do-a-paged-querydsl-query-with-spring-jpa